# can't start jupyter server outside base conda env

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I have miniconda installed with a base environment and an additional environment called plantcv. when I try to select plantcv in vs code as my environment it says "can't start a jupyter server from this environment". But I can launch jupyter notebook from both the base or plantcv environments using the cmd.

I've tried with VS COde, VS Code Insiders, and have removed all extensions except Python Extension Pack.

WIndows 10 1903, python 3.7, VS Code Insiders 1.37/VS Code 1.36

Is there something else I need to do to link conda and vs code?

EDIT:
[image: add]

Comment: Where does this error message show up? Is there a traceback as well?

Comment: @HåkenLid i added a screenshot above.  no traceback that I can see.

Comment: I don't know about miniconda and what exactly what "base environment" means, but typically virtual environments would be isolated from each other. Did you install jupyter in the plantcv environment?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't hbe able to open jupyter notebook from plantcv environment

Comment: i might not be the only one, i found this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5197

Comment: Yeah. Looks like the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug - see the discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5197

but I finally got around this by opening anaconda prompt (or git bash) then doing `conda activate plantcv` then `code .` and it works. if you `cd` to your project directory first then vs code will open in the right directory too.